# Frontend: why some fields are not in the $data param of the save function?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, jform, front-end

I'm using a frontend JForm to manipulate some data. The html form is correct, but when it is sent back to the model save function I don't receive all data.

This is the data that `save` receives through `$data` parameter:

```
Array
(
    [created] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [updated] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [wasteId] => X
    [price] => XXXX
    [pricenight] => XXX
    [pricefreeday] => XXXX
    [pricefreedaynight] => XXXX
    [tags] => 
)
```

But when I use

```
$formData = new JRegistry($this->input->get('jform', '', 'array'));
```

or when I got the data as the JControllerForm save method does

```
$formData = new JRegistry($this->input->post->get('jform', array(), 'array'));
```

I've got

```
Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
(
    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
        (
            [wasteId] => X
            [price] => XXXX
            [pricenight] => XXX
            [pricefreeday] => XXXX
            [pricefreedaynight] => XXXX
            [contractId] => Array
                (
                    [0] => XX
                    [1] => XX
                )

            [created] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            [updated] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            [id] => XX
        )
)
```

So fields `id` and `contractId` are missing in the `$data` parameter.

Any idea of what should I do to have `contractId` and id on the `$data` parameter of the model `save` function?

By the way, the model I'm using is derived from JModelAdmin and the controller is derived from JControllerForm. The controller has no overriden functions which may affect the way it collects data from the form.

**EDIT**

More clues: inspecting the `JControllerForm::save` more in detail I've seen that `$data` has the `id` component with the correct value but it gets overwritten with an empty value around line 637 because of this:

```
$recordId = $this->input->getInt($urlVar); // around line 634 of JControllerForm
```

sets `$recordId` to an empty value, in spite of `$urlVar` value is "id". Then later, around line 637 of JControllerForm $data["id"] is changed:

```
$data[$key] = $recordId
```

`$key` value is "id" and `$recordId` is empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show any of your code, so I'm just going to walk through what I know of `JControllerForm` and `JModelAdmin` — which of course will be affected by any overrides in your subclass.

**JControllerForm**

The `save()` method in `JControllerForm` uses the following line to retrieve the `JForm` array.

```
$data  = $this->input->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```

Note the extra `->post` segment vs. your `JRegistry()` test, that means it's only getting the data from the `post` data submitted. Your example uses the combined `JInput` as a source. It's unlikely, but if those fields are submitted as part of the form URL (i.e. in the `get` part of the submission) then they won't be found.

Without more details, e.g. form html, your controller & model code (esp. if you override save/bind etc) it's hard to say. If you can add more details I can probably expand on my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All data moves via post method, and the only overriden function overrided is the model's save, but because it's the parameter which is not filled correctly the code may be irrelevant. If I got the data from the post exactly as the controller does I've got the expected data.